# Placing EditTexts over an Imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-edittext

I want to make the user and password boxes EditTexts, so you can write text into them.
(having this layout).
[image]

What's the most suitable way to aproach this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Most suitable way is to design xml layout by yourself :)

Comment: you have to first try with your self. After that if you have problem we can help you!!

Comment: Use a LinearLayout, the green background must be set on the LinearLayout. Next, you need 2 TextViews and 2 EditTexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic sample, modify it to your need:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```